# Rails 3 nested form not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have looked through dozens of StackOverflow answers to essentially this question, but none quite helps! First off, I'm using Rails 3, so strong parameters aren't the answer.

I've got a SurveyUser model and a SurveyDemographic model, and each SurveyUser has one SurveyDemographic and each SurveyDemographic belongs to a SurveyUser.

```
class SurveyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :survey_demographic

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_demographic
  attr_accessible :password, :username, :survey_demographic_attributes
end

class SurveyDemographic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility
  belongs_to :survey_user
  attr_accessible :age, :gender
end
```

I have a nested form to create a survey user and fill in their demographic information:

```
= form_for @survey_user, :url => facility_survey_users_path(@facility) do |f|
  - if @survey_user.errors.any? || @survey_demographic.errors.any?
    %div#error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@survey_user.errors.count + @survey_demographic.errors.count, "error") prohibited this survey_user from being saved:
      %ul
        - @survey_user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
        - @survey_demographic.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  %table.su
    %tr
      %td Username *
      %td
        = f.text_field :username
    %tr
      %td Password *
      %td
        = f.text_field :password
    = fields_for :survey_demographics, @survey_user.survey_demographic do |a|
      %tr
        %td Gender
        %td.gender
          = a.text_field :gender
      %tr
        %td Age
        %td.age
          = a.text_field :age
  %div#actions
    = f.submit :class => 'button_link'
    = link_to 'Cancel', facility_path(params[:facility_id]), :class => "button_link cancel_link"
```

The forms display, whether I use fields_for or f.fields_for for the survey demographic information. I get the right stuff going through when I look at the log:

```
"survey_user"=>{"username"=>"Mona Lisa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, 
"survey_demographics"=>{"gender"=>"1", "age"=>"99"}, "commit"=>"Create Survey user",
"facility_id"=>"21"}
```

However, none of this survey_demographics data is being saved to the database. I'm creating a survey_demographic record with a survey_demographic_id each time, but all the entries are nil. I see in the log that the entry is created and then updated, but the update does not include any of this data.

When I used `fields_for`, I get no errors (it just doesn't work). When I use `f.fields_for`, I get "Warning: can't mass assign variables for survey_demographics!" even through I have `attr_accessible :survey_demographic_attributes` in my SurveyUser model.

My `survey_users_controller.rb` contains:

```
  def new
    @survey_user = SurveyUser.new
    @survey_demographic = @survey_user.build_survey_demographic
    @survey_user.facility = @facility
```

and

```
  def create
    @survey_user = SurveyUser.new(params[:survey_user])
    @survey_user.facility = @facility
    @survey_demographic = @survey_user.create_survey_demographic(params[:survey_demographic])
```

with appropriate end statements, and survey_demographic_controller has nothing not generated by Rails.

Should I be using `fields_for` or `f.fields_for`? Why does `f.fields_for` cause the mass-assignment error despite my `attr_accessible`? And ultimately, why is the data from the nested form not saving?

Comment: What happens when you use just `= f.fields_for :survey_demographic, do |a|`?

Comment: @Pavan, When I just use "f.fields_for :survey_demographic, do |a|" I get a slightly different set of parameters passed but it still does not save:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Nc6bnb3USOtWyH8iC1/19AeEnvKhcVvPytJYNbFksuc=", "survey_user"=>{"username"=>"Monalisa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "survey_demographic_attributes"=>{"gender"=>"1", "age"=>"98"}}, "commit"=>"Create Survey user", "facility_id"=>"21"}

Comment: And did you get any error? what about the previous error?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a nested form and using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` Rails expects the key that the nested attributes are created under to be in the format of `<association_name>_attributes`. In this case that would be `survey_demographic_attributes`,

You can adjust `fields_for` to use the correct key

```
= f.fields_for :survey_demographic_attributes, @survey_user.survey_demographic do |a|
```

however, Rails should be able to figure out the correct key on its own if you just do this:

```
= f.fields_for @survey_user.survey_demographic do |a|
```

In your code example you only use `fields_for` and not `f.fields_for`. Use `f.fields_for` so that survery_demographic is nested under survery_user.

Comment: I just tried it both ways (using f.fields_for) and unfortunately, still nothing is saved. I'm very puzzled! Could it be that I need something in my controller under 'def update'?

Comment: The only thing you should need in the controller is `SurveyUser.create(params[:survery_user])`. That's in the create  action btw, not update.

Comment: I do have SurveyUser.create(params[:survey_user]) in the controller. Guess that's good.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in the end:

```
= fields_for :survey_demographic do |a|
```

I don't understand 100%, but:

- The pluralization may have been wrong
- Now the hash is what it "should" be:

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"Nc6bnb3USOtWyH8iC1/19AeEnvKhcVvPytJYNbFksuc=", "survey_user"=>{"username"=>"Real One", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "survey_demographic"=>{"gender"=>"0", "age"=>"88"}, "commit"=>"Create Survey user", "facility_id"=>"21"}

In particular, this passes `survey_user => {stuff}, survey_demographic => {more stuff}` (not real code!) rather than `survey_user => {stuff, survey_demographic => {more stuff}}`. Note the nesting of {}.

What I still don't understand is why @survey_user.survey_demographic was the wrong thing.

Thanks for your answers, folks -- it was helpful in thinking through the problem! Pavan's answer got me looking at the key, and Sharagoz's thinking about the key name and position.